# In drools, I want to skip 'when' part to 'then' in rule, when first condition is satisfied (provided i have 3)

Tags: drools

```
`When A: (cond 1)  B: (cond 2)  C: (cond 3) Then........end
```

What i want to do is,there will be case where 1st condition is enough to process. so i want to move to then if 1st satisfied and i cannot have conditions in OR because of business limitations on domain.

Comment: currently i'm using two rules but it is causing delay in processing because of the huge data

Answer (score 0):

You can use Or in between rules. Like if (a>10) || (a<122) || ..so on.
It will work if any one condition is true.

Comment: The main thing to have in mind with this approach is that in the case you have 3 conditions with an `OR` and the 3 of them happen to be true, you will have 3 activations of the rule. There is no short-circuit `OR` between different patterns in Drools.

Comment: @EstebanAliverti Then to solve this problem Do we have to add 3 different rules? or Is there any better way of defining rules for this scenario?